# Rpy2 Unable to Load in Fresh QGIS Install

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, r, error

after installing qgis the a message given below is shown

Unable to load the plugin: Unable to load required package rpy2.
Please ensure that both R, and the corresponding version of Rpy2 are correctly installed.

please let me know why this is fault

Comment: When does this error occur? When you try to run QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Rpy2 is currently broken on windows:
http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Rpy2-broken-on-win-possible-alternatives-td4885899.html

However, if you don't need any of the rpy2 related plugins, you should still be able to run the rest of QGIS without problem.